# Javascript replace "variables" in HTML code faster

Tags: javascript, html, regex, angularjs, performance

I'm building a multi-language single page website with javascript and the new html `template`-tag and would like to use own variables like `{{txt.welcome}}` in html which should be replaced by the translation.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>{{heading.hello}}</h2>
  <p>{{txt.welcome}}<br /><img alt="{{image.description}}" src="" /></p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var reg = new RegExp(/{{([a-z.]+)}}/g);
var result;
while(result = reg.exec(document.documentElement.innerHTML)) {
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML.replace(result[0], translations[result[1]]);
}
```

It searchs for the variables in the whole document and replace them with the defined text, but with many variables the performance becomes really bad.

What would be a faster solution than looping with regex over the whole document's html?

How do it other libraries [like AngularJS](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide) with `{{ 'FOO' | translate }}`?

Comment: http://handlebarsjs.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest issue, I think, is that you are not just running a regex, but also running a replace over the entire HTML **multiple times**.  And you are setting the actual DOM HTML multiple times rather than manipulating a string until you get the result, and then setting the HTML once.  I would strongly recommend using a library like Handlebars.js, but if you want to do it yourself, a very quick implementation would be something like:

```
var translations = { 
    heading: { 
        hello: "hello" 
    }, 
    txt: { 
        welcome: "welcome" 
    }, 
    image: { 
        description: "this is a test" 
    }
};

function get(obj, desc) {
    var arr = desc.split(".");
    while(arr.length && (obj = obj[arr.shift()]));
    return obj;
}

function replaceTokens(HTML) {
    return HTML.split('{{').map(function(i) { 
        var symbol = i.substring(0, i.indexOf('}}')).trim(); 
        return i.replace(symbol + '}}', get(translations, symbol)); 
    }).join('');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's much faster. Can you explain why you do the things in the get()-function instead just `translations[symbol]`?

Comment: Yeah, if symbol is `heading.hello`, then I can either access the property by doing `translations.heading.hello` or by doing `translations['heading']['hello']`.  If I do `translations['heading.hello']` it won't find anything.  So I had to have a method to figure out the right property to access.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your regexp (with a little modification) to split your html in an array. Then you can replace only the template chunks of your array by their translations, and finally joining it and replacing the document html with it :

```
var html = "a little {{foo}} in the {{bar}}"; // replace with document.documentElement.innerHTML
var translations = {foo: "boy", bar: "garden"};
var chunks = html.split(/({{[a-z.]+}})/g);
var chunksTranslated = chunks.map(function(chunk){
  if(chunk.slice(0,2)==="{{" && chunk.slice(-2)==="}}") {
    var id = chunk.slice(2,-2);
    return translations[id];
  }
  return chunk;
});
var translatedHtml = chunksTranslated.join("");
//document.documentElement.innerHTML = translatedHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an existing template engine, rather than building your own.  There are a slew of them out there, and they're decently fast.

Evaluate a few options here:
http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/

[handlebarsjs](http://handlebarsjs.com/) seems to be the engine du jour.

John Ressig published a great "micro-templating" solution that is similar to your solution.  (http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)

> ```
> // Simple JavaScript Templating
> // John Resig - http://ejohn.org/ - MIT Licensed
> (function(){
>   var cache = {};
>
>   this.tmpl = function tmpl(str, data){
>     // Figure out if we're getting a template, or if we need to
>     // load the template - and be sure to cache the result.
>     var fn = !/\W/.test(str) ?
>       cache[str] = cache[str] ||
>         tmpl(document.getElementById(str).innerHTML) :
>
>       // Generate a reusable function that will serve as a template
>       // generator (and which will be cached).
>       new Function("obj",
>         "var p=[],print=function(){p.push.apply(p,arguments);};" +
>
>         // Introduce the data as local variables using with(){}
>         "with(obj){p.push('" +
>
>         // Convert the template into pure JavaScript
>         str
>           .replace(/[\r\t\n]/g, " ")
>           .split("<%").join("\t")
>           .replace(/((^|%>)[^\t]*)'/g, "$1\r")
>           .replace(/\t=(.*?)%>/g, "',$1,'")
>           .split("\t").join("');")
>           .split("%>").join("p.push('")
>           .split("\r").join("\\'")
>       + "');}return p.join('');");
>
>     // Provide some basic currying to the user
>     return data ? fn( data ) : fn;
>   };
> })();
> ```
>
> You would use it against templates written like this (it doesn’t have
>   to be in this particular manner – but it’s a style that I enjoy):
>
> ```
> <script type="text/html" id="item_tmpl">
>   <div id="<%=id%>" class="<%=(i % 2 == 1 ? " even" : "")%>">
>     <div class="grid_1 alpha right">
>       <img class="righted" src="<%=profile_image_url%>"/>
>     </div>
>     <div class="grid_6 omega contents">
>       <p><b><a href="/<%=from_user%>"><%=from_user%></a>:</b> <%=text%></p>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </script>
> ```