# JavaScript: Copy document DOM without reference

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to copy the document DOM (or a part of it) without reference?

For example:

```
BodyCopy = document.body;
document.body.querySelector('#example').innerHTML = '<p>foo</p>';
BodyCopy.querySelector('#example').innerHTML = '<p>bar</p>';

// will output <p>bar</p>, but should be <p>foo</p>
console.log(document.body.querySelector('#example').innerHTML);

// will output <p>bar</p>
console.log(BodyCopy.querySelector('#example').innerHTML);
```

**Update:**

Ok, clondeNode() seems first to work, but if I do

```
BodyCopy = document.body.cloneNode(true);
document.body.querySelector('#example').innerHTML = '<p>foo</p>';
BodyCopy.querySelector('#example').innerHTML = '<p>bar</p>';

// will output <p>foo</p>
console.log(document.body.querySelector('#example').innerHTML);

// will output <p>bar</p>
console.log(BodyCopy.querySelector('#example').innerHTML);

// Show edited copy
document.body = BodyCopy;

document.body.querySelector('#example').innerHTML = '<p>foo</p>';
BodyCopy.querySelector('#example').innerHTML = '<p>bar</p>';

// will output <p>bar</p>, but should be <p>foo</p>
console.log(document.body.querySelector('#example').innerHTML);

// will output <p>bar</p>
console.log(BodyCopy.querySelector('#example').innerHTML);
```

it will not work as I expect. See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkg70L38/).

Comment: Are you going to append cloned node in dom, or replace existing, or just work with it in js?

Comment: I will clone it, edit the cloned one and replace it multiple times. One copy should hold the original, one copy is for editing and the real document (`document.body`) should contain what's should be seen by user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> BodyCopy = document.body.cloneNode(true);
> // ...
> document.body = BodyCopy;
> ```

If you want to replace a node use [`parent.replaceChild(newChild, oldChild)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) or [`child.replaceWith(newChild)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith).

```
let rootNode = document.documentElement;
let currentBody = document.body;
rootNode.replaceChild(BodyCopy, currentBody);
```

This how the [body setter function](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-document-body) should be implemented according to the html spec anyway.

If you want to keep the copy independent of the new content you'll have to clone it again before replacing the old one;

Manipulating innerHTML should be avoided where possible since it has to round-trip the nodes through the HTML serializer and parser.

Answer (score 5):

You're not copying the DOM anywhere, you're assigning `document.body` to a variable called `BodyCopy`.

You need to use [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) on the assignment:

```
BodyCopy = document.body.cloneNode(true);
```

---

```
var BodyCopy = document.body.cloneNode(true);
document.body.querySelector('#example').innerHTML = '<p>foo</p>';
BodyCopy.querySelector('#example').innerHTML = '<p>bar</p>';

// Now outputs <p>foo</p>
console.log(document.body.querySelector('#example').innerHTML);

// Now outputs <p>bar</p>
console.log(BodyCopy.querySelector('#example').innerHTML);
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tcub3rn7/)

Comment: Thank you, but for changes after showing edited copy `document.body = BodyCopy;` it will not work. See updated question.

Comment: @Kiltarc You will need to replace the `innerHTML` of `body`. But then, why do you even need to do that? It's a lot of processing power when you could (and arguably *should*) be working directly with `document.body` anyway...
Also, don't move the goalposts. You received the correct answer to your initial question. If you have other questions, add them as a separate post here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That seems to does the trick. In the application it is kind more complex. This was my initial question, but my example was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [clone the node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) before performing modifications:

```
BodyCopy = document.body.cloneNode(true);
```

Now you have a copy instead of a reference.

**EDIT**

If you want to replace the old `document.body` with the new `BodyCopy`, you should modify its content and not its reference:

```
document.body.innerHTML = BodyCopy.innerHtml;
```

Comment: yes,have clone of node but the id is same.So,it will gives same behaviur

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN no it won't, because you're running the selector on a completely different element. See the jsFiddle demo in my answer.

Comment: @RIKAY KHAN Thank you, but for changes after showing edited copy `document.body = BodyCopy;` it will not work. See updated question.

Comment: @Kiltarc I have no idea why you'd want to do that. Why not just work directly with `document.body` if your intention is to replace it at the end of the process with your 'working copy' anyway?

Comment: Because that costs performance if I have to do many changes to the DOM, or I'm wrong?

Comment: What makes you think that? You're doing them anyway with a cloned node of `body`, and then writing everything back to `document.body`.

Comment: Because the clone is not in the document and the copy is in memory and not real DOM.. or so.. I'm wrong?

Comment: No, you're wrong. Both are in memory. It is far more performant to just modify the `body` DOM node, than to have multiple read/write operations to it.

Comment: But if I assign the innerHTML to a variable, change it multiple times and then reassign it to the DOM node it will be a performance impact? Someone told me that here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32150573/5186688

Comment: setting innerhtml is inefficient, there's no reason to do it if you already have dom nodes.